# I have a problem sending messages from selenium to facebook accounts

Tags: vb.net

I can send messages to Facebook accounts by selenium, but there are some closed accounts that do not accept messages from non-friendly parties. I want to skip these messages and complete the following message

```
Function SendMessage(ByVal Account As String, ByVal Message As String) As Integer
        Getcounts()
        Try
            t.Navigate.GoToUrl("https://m.facebook.com/" & Account)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return 2
            Exit Function
        End Try

        WaitTcompleteLoding()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Try
            Dim a As OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement

            For Each a In t.FindElementsByClassName("_56bz")
                Try
                    If a.GetAttribute("href").ToString.ToLower.Contains("facebook.com/messages/") Then
                        Try
                            a.Click()
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Return 2
                            Exit Function
                        End Try

                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try

            Next

            '  t.FindElementsByClassName("_56bz")(2).Click()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return 2
            Exit Function
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

_56bz

variable element and no longer exists if the profile is closed for messages